# "import" a definition of a function from a base class to implement abstract interface (multiple inheritance in C++)

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance, pure-virtual

Say we have a class inheriting from two base classes (multiple inheritance). Base `class A` is abstract, declaring a pure virtual function `foo`, the other base `class B` declares and implements a function `foo` of the very same signature.

```
struct A
{
  virtual void foo(int i) = 0;
};

struct B
{
  virtual void foo(int i) {}
};

struct C : public A, public B {};
```

I want to use the implementation of `foo` from base `class B` in my derived `class C`. However, if I do not implement the function `foo` a second time in my derived `class C`, I cannot instantiate any object of it (it remains abstract). Virtual inheritance does not help here as expected (`class A` and `class B` have no common base class).

I wonder if there is a way to "import" the implementation of `foo` from `class B` into `class C` in order not to have to repeat the same code.

Above example is of course contrived. The reason I want implement `foo` in `class B` is that I want to derive `class D : public B` and use `class B`s implementation of `foo`. I know that inheritance is not (primarily) intended for code reuse, but I'd still like to use it in that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java, your sample code works. In C++ it doesn't. A subtle difference between those languages.

Your best option in C++ is to define C::foo() by forwarding to B::foo():

```
struct C : public A, public B
{
  virtual void foo(int i) { B::foo(i); }
};
```