# Why can't I use inheritance to implement an interface in C++?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implementing abstract class members in a parent class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167558/implementing-abstract-class-members-in-a-parent-class)
>   [Why does C++ not let baseclasses implement a derived class' inherited interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464308/why-does-c-not-let-baseclasses-implement-a-derived-class-inherited-interface)

Considering these objects:

```
struct A
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct B
{
    void foo() { /* neat implementation */ }
};
```

I wonder why --compiler-wise-- the following object is considered abstract:

```
struct C : B, A
{
    using B::foo; // I tried my best to make the compiler happy
};
```

The compiler won't let me do this:

```
A* a = new C;
```

Visual Studio 2010 says:

> 'C' : cannot instantiate abstract class due to following members: 'void A::foo(void)' : is abstract : see declaration of 'A::foo'

g++ 4.6.3 says:

> cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘C’ because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘C’: virtual void A::foo()

I guess this is allowed in C#, but I don't know the involved mecanism(s) -- I am just being curious.

Comment: The closest you get is probably something like `template<class Base> struct B: Base{ void foo() {...} };` and then `struct C: B<A> {};`.

Comment: One more duplicate is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291568/import-a-definition-of-a-function-from-a-base-class-to-implement-abstract-inte/3291620

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`struct B` is implementing a function that happens to be called `foo` and takes no arguments. That function has obviously absolutely no relation to `A::foo`. So when `struct C` derives from both `A` and `B`, it ends up having inherited:

- the responsibility to provide an implementation for `A::foo`
- a method `B::foo` that has the same name and signature as `A::foo`, but is not related to it in any way

I think the problem is obvious. You are trying to use `A` as the equivalent of a C# `interface`, but there is no way to express that concept in C++.

Now the `using` directive also does not help here because all it does is bring `B::foo` into the scope of `C`, meaning that it tells the compiler it should consider `B::foo` as a candidate for resolving the name `foo` when the latter is encountered inside class `C`. Unfortunately, that's also unrelated to the responsibility of implementing pure virtual methods.

Comment: one could argue that `using` would explicitly bridge the two. It does not (in effect) but it could. This is, of course, wishful thinking.

Comment: @MatthieuM. - do you happen to know if that's a concious design decision not to make `using` have that meaning here, or just that nobody ever proposed it?

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Sorry, editing. I think the current answer covers that as well.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: "It could" doesn't mean "it should"

Comment: @awoodland: I don't know. I wish C++ would have better support for delegation (specifically to attributes, something like `using v::insert` would be awesome to avoid the derive to inherit behavior we see so often); on the other hand it's just a couple one-liners away, so it is mostly syntactic sugar.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Syntactic sugar can be of *monumental* importance. Would you rather see inline lambdas or a few dozen one-shot classes in your code base? I 'm so spoiled by C#'s excellent lambda syntactic sugar that I find C++03 *barbaric* in comparison.

Comment: @Jon: I did not say it was not useful. Hey, my personal preference in C++11 goes to the range-for construct! It may be time to propose it, delegation *is* interesting (practically); however what is great with syntactic sugar, is that we can work in the mean time with minimal fuss. I prefer emulating delegation with inliners than emulating move semantics with `auto_ptr` ;)

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Agreed. It's just that in 2012, and mainly due to the excellent work of the C# team, I feel sad when the compiler forces me to go through pure red tape (although admittedly the C++ standards committee has abysmally less freedom of movement than MS does with C#).

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, this does not quite do what you want.

A `using` directive is just about bringing some names into the scope it is used. `virtual` methods need be overriden, and *just* bringing names is not considered overriding.

The truth of the matter is that C++ does not support *delegation* directly. There is just this slight twist of bringing names into scope explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this one, you need to implement your own `foo()` within C and explicitly call the B function--effectively forwarding A::foo to B::foo within C:

```
struct C : B, A
{
  virtual void foo() {
    // Override A::foo by forwarding to B::foo:
    B::foo();
  }
};
```

It makes sense at some level--there is no inherent relation between A::foo() and B::foo()--you have to explicitly establish one within C.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess this is allowed in C#

C++ is not C#.

`virtual void foo()` and `void foo()` are two different methods.

When you derive from both A and B, you get access to two methods: `virtual A::foo` and non-virtual `B::foo`. And `virtual A::foo` is abstract. Hence the compiler error.