# Provide implementation to pure virtual function through multiple inheriting another class

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“import” a definition of a function from a base class to implement abstract interface (multiple inheritance in C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291568/import-a-definition-of-a-function-from-a-base-class-to-implement-abstract-inte)

Suppose I have a base class

```
struct Base1 { virtual void f() = 0; };
```

and another class that provides implementation for function `f`:

```
struct Base2 { virtual void f() {} };
```

I wanted to use `Base2::f` to implement `Base1::f` through multiple inheritance:

```
struct C : Base1, Base2 {};
```

But look like compiler doesn't do what I expected, and `C` is still abstract.

So what is the best way to provide implementation to a pure virtual through another class?

Thanks.

Comment: This has been already asked today. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533772/why-cant-i-use-inheritance-to-implement-an-interface-in-c

Comment: Although I have to admit that the title of this question is much better than the title of the one from 2010. It's understandable it wasn't found by OP.